# Detect OS text size on win7

Tags: c++, windows-7

I would like to detect (via c++) what the user has chosen for text size, i.e.:

Smaller - 100%
Medium - 125%
Larger - 150%

Seems like an easy one, just can't seem to find the answer....

thanks,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changes the DPI for the DISPLAY device.  Use GetDeviceCaps(), LOGPIXELSX/Y.  Use CreateIC(L"DISPLAY", 0, 0, 0) to create the DC.  The percentage value corresponds to 96, 120 and 144 dots-per-inch.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN has a comprehensive reference on DPI awareness, although it's rather long.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660(VS.85).aspx) The correct function is GetDeviceCaps, using LOGPIXELSX and LOGPIXELSY to determine the DPI in each dimension. (These are not guaranteed to be the same.) Documentation for GetDeviceCaps is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877(VS.85).aspx).